# Windows 8.1 Pro lists me as Online and Offline all at Once

Tags: windows-8.1

For some reason, the internet connection icon in my Windows 8.1 Task Tray is showing me as both online and offline, and the online part of the message that it is showing me is for a network that I used to use frequently but no longer use. It's impossible to tell what I am talking about just by my description, so here's a screenshot of it.

[image: Internet Access shows Online and Offline]

Obviously this is not a high-priority issue, but it's something that's bothering the geek in me that demands perfection in all ways possible. As a sidenote, earlier today I was trying to connect to another network and it was not allowing me on any website other than Google and Google-related websites. It was after coming home and reconnecting to my network that I noticed this.

[image: Network and Sharing Center]

Comment: You have multiple network devices that Windows is picking up this is perfectly normal. If you have any program that creates a virtual network device the "unidentified network" likely is that.  You didn't provide enough information to give you a specific answer though.

Comment: @Ramhound Did I mention in my question that the blurred out connection in the picture above is not the same one that I was connected to whenever the picture was taken?

Comment: No...You actually didn't but that doesn't change the fact nothing in my comments even mention the blurred out connection since it has nothing to do with the `Unidentified Network`.  I still maintain that its likely a virtual network device.  Hamachi, VMWare/VirtualBox/HyperV all will create a virtual lan device which won't be connected to the internet for obvious reasons.  Some VPN software will create a virtual network device also

Comment: @Ramhound Just checked Task Manager. I have two Ethernet graphs listed. One doesn't ever show anything happening o it. Now how can I fix the problem with the network listing being wrong?

Comment: **Its not wrong though....**  You will need to post a screenshot of `Network Sharing Center` and we will also need a screenshot of `Network Connection` located at `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah, I have a connection with that name listed.

Comment: @Ramhound Added screenshot. One with missing name is the one that has the name of my old internet connection that I no longer use because I renamed it.

Comment: Anyways you can delete the network connection in `Network Connection` which is the reason I asked for that information also.  Of course if you do that your `Windows Phone Emulator` will stop working.  As I originally indicate this behavior is to be expected.  If you have other questions with regards to this come to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14160/discussion-between-ramhound-and-davidb)

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand what to do here. Wouldn't that screw things up?

Comment: [Come to the Chat....](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14160/discussion-between-ramhound-and-davidb) I can't help unless you do this.